# Can one view GitHub files in fullscreen?

Tags: github, repository, syntax-highlighting, azure-repos, github-enterprise

Is it possible to view a file on GitHub in fullscreen mode with syntax highlighting like one can on an Azure Repo?

[image]

Comment: The only way that I know of is to click on the **Raw** button to view the raw contents of any file. But it's not specifically possible to view a file in full screen with the editor-like UI.

Comment: I wish the `Raw` view had color coding.